# Подскажите, как обрезать строку от имени до последнего символа ","?

Tags: powershell, split

`Dear Anastasia; 1223 Budapest; 13 Nov 2021,`

Мне отсюда нужно получить `Dear Anastasia,` с помощью команды `split`

Comment: `'Dear Anastasia; 1223 Budapest; 13 Nov 2021,' -replace '([^;]+);[^,]+,', '$1,'`

Comment: `'Dear Anastasia; 1223 Budapest; 13 Nov 2021,'.Split(';')[0]`

Answer (score 0):

```
$en = "Dear Anastasia; 1223 Budapest; 13 Nov 2021,".GetEnumerator()
$StringBuilder = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new()
for ($($i = 0; $startFlag = $false); $en.MoveNext();){
    if ($en.Current -eq ";") {$startFlag = $true    } 
    if ($en.Current-eq ','){
        $StringBuilder.ToString()
        break
    }
    if ($startFlag){
        $null = $StringBuilder.Append($en.Current)
    }
}



("Dear Anastasia; 1223 Budapest; 13 Nov 2021,".Split(";")[1,2] -join ';').TrimEnd(',')
```